# C++ - Check if there are no even numbers in given interval

Tags: c++

I have to write a program on C++ which finds all even numbers in range given by user. Here's the code I have written so far:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main() {
int m, n, j = 1; // m and n- numbers entered by user, j- product of all even numbers in interval
char atbilde; // A letter entered by user, of which system decides wether to continue or to stop programme

do {
    j = 1;
    cout << "Enter the min number of interval!  ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the max number of interval!  ";
    cin >> m;
    if (n > m) { // Detects wether „n” is larger than „m”
cout << "Max number of interval has to be larger than min number!";
        do { // If max number is larger than min number, screen is cleared
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Enter the numbers again!";
            cout << "\n Enter the min number of interval!  ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\n Enter the max number of interval!  ";
            cin >> m;
        }
        while (n > m);
    }

    cout << "Even  numbers in given interval: ";
    for (; n <= m; n++)
    { 
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        { // Detects, wether there are even numbers in given interval
                if (n != 0) {

                    cout << n << " ";
                    j *= n;

                }

                if ((n == m) && (n % 2 != 0)) {
                    j=0;
                }

        }

    }
        cout << "\n The product of found even numbers: " << j << " ";


    cout << "\n Repeat? (Y/N) ";
    cin >> answer;
    system("cls");

}
while (tolower(answer) != 'n');
}
```

But I have a small problem, so I can't get the program 100% done because of the problem. 
Like, user enters range, whose min and max number is the same and it's odd. In that case program has to print out a sentence "there were no even numbers in interval" in place of "The product of found even numbers:". I have searched the solution in internet, but haven't found it.
I hope you'll know the right solution.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Several life advices: 1- Study how HW works (doing modulo each time is probably not the best thing to do) 2 - First think about problem in your mind and then try to figure out all possible cases, that can go wrong. => Solve them first. 3 - You should inform user about the INT range

Comment: Some advice: 0) `iostream` is not `iostream.h`.  Also, for C library headers, you might want to use the `cX` verison instead of the `X.h` version (e.g. `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`).  1) You use the names `atbilde` and `answer` for the same variable; choose one or the other.  2) `void main()` is a non-standard extenstion.  While Visual Studio supports it, not all compilers are guaranteed to do so.  If you want to make your code more portable, you can use the standard `int main()`.

Comment: 3) You can replace the `do...while` loop in your `if (n > m)` statement's body with `continue`, which will go to the main loop's condition check; if you do so, I suggest initialising the `char` to `'y'`, and change string `"Max number of interval has to be larger than min number!"` to `"Max number of interval has to be larger than min number!\nPut the numbers again!\n"`, so the behaviour stays the same.

Comment: 4) Assuming the range is inclusive (i.e. the range `3..5` consists of `3, 4, 5`), there is exactly one situation where the range will contain no even numbers, which you have mentioned in your question.  You can check for this situation with an `if`; when encountered, you can provide your desired special output, prompt the user for whether they want to continue, and use `continue` to restart the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to help you along the way: If there was no even number in the range, you will not enter into the loop. What will `j` be then? How do you react on that value?

Comment: this really should be a comment if this is all you are going to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix your code, I did the best I could from what I understood you were tring to do.
I cleaned it up, fixed spelling and grammer, I deleted unnecessary stuff, I also made it more compact and nice to look at.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int max=0, min=1, sum=0; product = 1, amount = 0; // max, min - entered by user, product - product of all even numbers in interval, sum - sum of all even numbers in interval. amount - amount of even numbers in interval
    char x=Y; // Entered by user to know if to quit or continue to continue.

    while ((x == Y) || (x == y))
    {
        while (min > max) { // System detects whether minimum is bigger than maximum
            cin.clear();  // Clears screen so if this part runs again it wouldn't get messy.
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Max has to be larger than min!";
            cout << "\n Enter the min number of interval!  ";
            cin >> min;
            cout << "\n Enter the max number of interval!  ";
            cin >> max;
        }

        for (; min <= max; min++)
        {
            if (min % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum+=n;
                count++;
                product*=n;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            product=0;
            cout << "There are no even numbers in interval!";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n The amount of the even numbers in interval: " << amount << ",the product of the even numbers: " << product << ",the sum of the even numbers: " sum << "\n\n";
        }
        cout << "Repeat? (Y/N) ";
        x=getchar;
        system("cls");
    }
    return 0;
}
```